# ておく → とく in other contexts; similar 2-kana to 1-kana shortcuts?

Tags: て-form, colloquial-language, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

Recently I learned that おいておいて ("leave it there") can be shortened in casual speech (or speech to subordinates) to おいといて. (ておく → とく).

I also learned that this can be used for any verb attached to ておく (つけておく → つけとく; "leave it on").

1. Can the てお → と shortcut be used for contexts other than ておく (for example: お世話になっております → おせわになっとります)?
2. Are there other 2-kana to 1-kana shortcuts? (ていう to って, い抜き言葉 and ら抜き言葉 are interesting shortcuts, but the idea of shortening 2 kana to 1 kana sounded interesting to me for some reason.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "1.  Can the てお -> と shortcut be used for contexts other than ておく (for example: お世話になっ**てお**ります -> おせわになっ**と**ります)?"

The なっ**てお**ります-to-なっ**と**ります contraction does happen dialectally.  You will hear it ***many*** times daily in Central Japan and Kansai.  I am sure that it is used in many other parts of Western Japan as well.

Around Tokyo, you will rarely hear it used.  When you hear it, the speaker would usually be someone from Western Japan or Central Japan. **The ておく-to-とく contraction for the meaning of "doing something in advance", however, is used heavily around Tokyo as well**.

> "2.  Are there other 2-kana to 1-kana shortcuts? (ていう to って, い抜き言葉 and ら抜き言葉 are interesting shortcuts, but the idea of shortening 2 kana to 1 kana sounded interesting to me for some reason.)"

Yes, there certainly are.　I will include the ones with reduced syllable counts if not reduced kana counts.

> ている ⇒ てる　（[食]{た}べている ⇒ 食べてる）
>
> でいる ⇒ でる　（[飲]{の}んでいる ⇒ 飲んでる）
>
> ていく ⇒ てく　（[見]{み}ていく ⇒ 見てく）
>
> でいく ⇒ でく　（[休]{やす}んでいく ⇒ 休んでく）
>
> ては ⇒ ちゃ　（なくては ⇒ なくちゃ）
>
> では ⇒ じゃ　（[泳]{およ}いではいけない ⇒ 泳いじゃいけない）
>
> てあげる ⇒ たげる　（キスしてあげる ⇒ キスしたげる）

I feel like there should be more.

Comment: just thought of せる -> す (頑張らせる -> 頑張らす) and せら -> さ (頑張らせられる -> 頑張らされる). Are these used often?

Comment: @rhyaeris Yes, very often, but we don't call it contraction. You can rather say it's alternative form of the causative せる.

Comment: @rhyaeris ～す is actually an older form than ～せる.

Comment: You forgot なければ to なきゃ

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, for example...

> ～ておいで -> ～といで  e.g. 持っておいで -> 持っといで
>   ～ておくれ -> ～とくれ  e.g. 来ておくれ -> 来とくれ　(← might be Edo/Tokyo dialect)

2. Yes, for example...

> ～でしまう -> ～じまう (でし→じ) e.g. 死んでしまう -> 死んじまう (→ often contracted to 死んじゃう)
>   ～てしまう -> ～ちまう (てし→ち) e.g. やってしまう -> やっちまう (→ often contracted to やっちゃう)
>   ～てあげる -> ～たげる (てあ→た) e.g. 買ってあげる -> 買ったげる
>   ～であげる -> ～だげる (であ→だ) e.g. 読んであげる -> 読んだげる
>   ～てやる -> ～たる (てや→た) e.g. 買ってやる -> 買ったる (← used in the west)
>   ～でやる -> ～だる (でや→だ) e.g. 読んでやる -> 読んだる (← used in the west)

Comment: て/でやる→た/だる is not much popular around me. Maybe some western dialects?

Comment: そうですね、確かに関西、九州・・・っぽい感じがします。