# what is grammar pattern for やさしくった

Tags: spoken-language, abbreviations

I watched a series. There is a scene, while subtitle text is written as 優しく言ってあげた　I heard something like やさしくったあげた。　so I did some search to check if this usage exist in real world. In google I found some, but in twitter there are few of tweet using やさしくった。　the following are my questions,

1. what is grammar pattern for this? is やさしくった abbreviation form of 優しく言って?
2. are there any resources (book/website/etc.) about Japanese spoken language? I try searching for book using 口語　but I don't think that is what I want.

Also I feel that there is a high probability to be just a mismatch between subtitle and voice.

here is the [sound file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgzDHZ5g1Kxulp4ZqfcWTuUpuhhpIA) 
(now that @l'électeur mentioned this and I wonder why I don't record the sound. Thank you for your suggestion!)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `優しくてあげた` -- Are you sure it was not 「優しく**し**てあげた」? `優しくった` -- Probably you misheard 「優しく**し**た」, no?

Comment: ah sorry actually in subtitle it's 優しくて言ってあげた。and there is a probability that I misheard it to be やさしくった

Comment: "やさしくった" has literally 60 hits on Google. It's a mistake.

Comment: @blackthorn enclose your query phrase in "quotes", this will search for the exact matches, be sure to request desktop version if on mobile, that way you'll see the number of hits. It's very useful, for example you can check yourself if you doubt how exactly to phrase something.

Comment: `優しくて言ってあげた。` -- I think it's 優しく言ってあげた (優しく, not 優しく**て**  )

Comment: Ｔ＾Ｔ @Chocolate, yeah, it's really　優しく言ってあげた. but on my listening part I can't say anything for sure as the character talk a bit too fast for me

Comment: ～ **てあ**げた can be shortened to ～ **た**げた (see here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30996/9831 "し**てあ**げる→し**た**げる") but the [言]{い} can't be dropped, i.e. ～言ってあげた can be shortened to ～言ったげた but not to just ～ったげた

Comment: The girl so clearly says 「優しく言ってあげた」.

Comment: The recorded voice says, もうちょっと、女子にはやさしく言ってあげた方がいいと思うよ。

Comment: my flight hour is not high enough so that I still heard 優しく言ってあげた as 優しくったあげた。but just as @Chocolate said してあげる can be pronoun as したげる. so I think what I heard it's actually come from 優しく言って（あげた）＞＞　優しく言ったげた。and due to my inexperience that I can't hear 言い sound clearly, it's became 優しくった(げた)。

Answer (score 4):

In Standard Japanese, the ***only*** correct and natural use of 「やさしくった」 would be within the phrase:

> 「やさしくったって」

which means "***even if (someone) were gentle***" or "***even if (something) were easy***" in very informal speech.  Drop the first 「っ」 and it will become a tiny bit less informal.  You might want to listen to the beginning of this song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysOL_EK_S2U

That is to say any other usage of 「やさしくった」 would be a mistake, typo, mishearing, etc.

> 1. what is grammar pattern for this? is やさしくった abbreviation form of 優しく言って?

No, 「やさしくった」 would never be an abbreviation of 「優{やさ}しく言{い}って」 in Standard Japanese (or any other "major" dialects I know of.)

**「優しく言って」 cannot even be abbreviated in the first place**.

> 2. are there any resources (book/website/etc.) about Japanese spoken language? I try searching for book using 口語　but I don't think that is what I want.

Questions about resouces are off-topic here.  Perhaps the Japanese-learners here could give advice as I am not one myself.

Thus, 「やさしくったあげた」 makes no sense, sorry to say.  That sounds just so nonsensical to my Japanese ears if I may add.

> Also I feel that there is a high probability to be just a mismatch between subtitle and voice.

More like between subtitles and the viewers' listening comprehension skills.  If you provide an audio, this problem will be solved in an instant.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there is even higher chance for me to misheard it. and hear is the sound file. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgzDHZ5g1Kxulp4ZqfcWTuUpuhhpIA