# What does してて mean?

Tags: translation

I was watching an [Easy Japanese](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qzzweIQoIOU) video on YouTube.

At 1:37, the interviewer says:

> 素敵。やっぱり普段生活**してて**も感じる？あ、優しいって。

What does `してて` mean? Or is it a typo? `して` makes sense here, but I don't understand `してて`. It's there in both the Japanese script and the English transliteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30996/9831), い in 「てform + subsidiary verb いる」 can get dropped in casual speech, eg 見ている→見てる, している→してる, so..

> 生活**してて**も感じる

is a colloquial pronunciation of..

> 生活**していて**も感じる

生活していて is the te-form of 生活している, "be living", "be leading a life". It's like the progressive/continuous form, as opposed to the present/plain form (=「生活する」"live", "live a life").

In your example, 「～て(い)て」 is used to mean "while (you're) doing~~":

> 普段生活していても感じる？
>   *lit.* "You're living a daily life, and you feel it, too?"
>   → "Do you (still/also) feel it while you're living a daily life? / in your daily life?"

<sub>The 普段 is functioning as an adverb here, "normally" "usually" or "daily" (since we don't have a compound noun 「普段生活」). The も adds a nuance of "too", "also", "still", or "even".</sub>

Some examples using 「～～て(い)て～～」 "~~ while/when doing~~":

> 歩い**て(い)て**ころんだ。 I fell while walking.
>   料理し**て(い)て**指を切った。 I cut my finger while cooking.
>   目をつぶっ**て(い)ても**できる。 I can do it even with my eyes closed.