# て-form + く - what does adding ku to a te-formed verb mean?

Tags: て-form

In:

よし じゃあ 出席**取ってく**ぞ

what does adding "く" mean for the verb?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30996/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/9831

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate. None of the possibilities seem to reference てく->ていく.

Comment: ん？　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30996/9831 に、「ていく ⇒ てく（[見]{み}ていく ⇒ 見てく）」って書いてあるやん。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「てく」is often a contracted form of 「ていく」, so your sentence means

> よし、じゃあ出席**を**取って**い**くぞ

> Okay, I am going to take attendance now.

where 「ていく」is a helping verb that tells you the action starts now in a forward looking manner.